# Node.js, Angular, express-session: Chrome 80 does not save session because of cookie policy (sameSite cookies)

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, express-session, samesite

I have a Node.js, Angular app. (Node.js server written in TypeScript).
Node.js Server is running on an Amazon EC-2 instance, the Angular client is on another server.

**For the login session, I use express-session. I am not using cookies in the app, so I think the problem is with the express-session cookies.**
On Firefox it works properly, but with Google Chrome (80.0.3987.149) it not works: Chrome doesn't save the session (so I can not leave the login page) and warns:

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://addressof.myserverapp.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

In Node.js server I set the express-sessions this way:

```js
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
app.use(cookieParser(secret));

app.use(session({
    secret: secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: null,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none'
    },
    store: sessionStore // MySqlStore - express-mysql-session
}));
```

I also tried to solve the problem with this code snippet (from https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/725#issuecomment-605922223)

```js
Object.defineProperty(session.Cookie.prototype, 'sameSite', {
    // sameSite cannot be set to `None` if cookie is not marked secure
    get() {
        return this._sameSite === 'none' && !this.secure ? 'lax' : this._sameSite;
    },
    set(value) {
        this._sameSite = value;
    }
});
```

Server npm packages:

```
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-mysql-session": "^2.1.3",
"express-session": "^1.17.0",
```

```
Npm version: 6.13.4
Node version: 12.16.1
```

I spent days with this problem to figure out what am I doing wrong...

Comment: Can you include an example of the `Set-Cookie` header that is being sent? As you point out, it does look like `express-session` should support the `SameSite=None; Secure` attributes so we need to take a look at what's being sent and received. We have a more complete debugging guide here: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are accessing the Website via HTTP, but the cookie `secure` setting is `true`, which means that it will only be sent via HTTPS.

If you set `secure: false` in the `express-session` cookie options, it will work:

```js
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
app.use(cookieParser(secret));

app.use(session({
    secret: secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: false,
        maxAge: null,
        // allow the cookie to be sent via HTTP ("true" means "HTTPS only)
        secure: false, 
        sameSite: 'lax'
    },
    store: sessionStore
}));
```

Comment: `secure: false` will not work with `sameSite: 'none'` in Chrome 80+